# How do I select this li item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple .listings-channel-rows but only want to show/hide the .listings-details-row within its own parent list. I think I'm along the right lines but can't quite figure out the syntax. Any help?

The HTML:

```html
<li class="listings-channel-row clearfix">
    <a href="#" class="listings-program toggle borderbottom">
        Back to the future 2 <span class="year">(1989
    </a>
    <li class="listings-details-row collapse-down">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam amet dolor accusamus itaque aspernatur exercitationem optio neque minima at nisi. Distinctio blanditiis vero porro saepe nesciunt explicabo deserunt aspernatur quasi.</p>
    </li>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```js
$(function () { 
    $(".toggle").on( "click", function () {
        $(this).parent().children('li').toggle('fast');
        $(this).toggleClass("borderbottom");
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't put an `li` immediately within another `li`. [It's illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `.next()`

http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
$(this)
  .toggleClass("borderbottom")
  .next().toggle('fast');
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Nor do any of the other suggestions on the page :/ Tried almost every variation I can think of but can only get all of the .collapse-down lists to show. Just can't seem to target one of them without using an ID

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(function () { 
    $(".toggle").on( "click", function() {
        $(this).siblings('.listings-details-row').toggle('fast');
        $(this).toggleClass("borderbottom");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To select a child you can just use the child selector
`$(".listings-channel-rows .listings-channel-rows")`

or if you want to select the direct child you can use
`$(".listings-channel-rows > .listings-channel-rows")`